# Web Scraping IE NAVIGATE method Works Vs MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 not Working

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am pulling data from NSE site,
the URL is:https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=VOLTAS&instrument=FUTSTK&type=-&strike=-&expiry=28MAY2020#

[image: Screen shot]

I am successfully extract the item using Internet explorer,How ever this method is slow,
so i moved to MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 method,but this method returns null string

please find my codes

```
Method 1:Works fine
Sub OI_Slow_Method()
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Dim Link As String
Link = ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value

ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate Link
Do

DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = ie.document

Dim objElement As HTMLObjectElement
Dim sDD As String

doc.Focus

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = doc.getElementById("openInterest").innerText 'Open Interest Value


ie.Quit
ie.Visible = True
Set doc = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
'--------------------------

Method 2:Help required in this method only
Sub OI_Fast_Method()
    Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=VOLTAS&instrument=FUTSTK&type=-&strike=-&expiry=30APR2020#", False
        .send
         html.body.innerHTML = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

  Debug.Print html.getElementById("openInterest").Innertext 
  'The output of this is "<SPAN id=openInterest>??</SPAN>" only question mark returned inside the SPAN
End Sub
```

Comment: When you navigate to a page using IE (or any browser), then that page may contain scripts which further add content to the page (by building elements from data embedded in the page, or by requesting additional data from the server).   The doesn't happen when you use XmlHttp - all you get is the raw page source as delivered by the server: nothing else- no images, scripts etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think Tim hit the nail on the head, as always.  You are getting some raw XML and the stuff you want is not in that XML.  You can do a data dump and get what you want.

```
Sub DumpData()

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True

URL = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=VOLTAS&instrument=FUTSTK&type=-&strike=-&expiry=28MAY2020#"

'Wait for site to fully load
ie.Navigate2 URL
Do While ie.Busy = True
   DoEvents
Loop

RowCount = 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")
   .Cells.ClearContents
   RowCount = 1
   For Each itm In ie.Document.all
      .Range("B" & RowCount) = Left(itm.innerText, 1024)
   RowCount = RowCount + 1
   Next itm
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Then you would have to parse the text.  It's not hard, but it will be a little extra labor.

Another option may be to download the entire contents of the website, save it as a text file, import the data, and then parse that data.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim retStr As String

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With ie
        .Navigate "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=VOLTAS&instrument=FUTSTK&type=-&strike=-&expiry=28MAY2020#"
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While ie.readystate <> 4: Wait 5: Loop

    DoEvents

    retStr = ie.document.body.innerText

    '~> Write the above to a text file
    Dim filesize As Integer
    Dim FlName As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant path
    FlName = "C:\Users\ryans\OneDrive\Desktop\Sample.Txt"

    filesize = FreeFile()

    Open FlName For Output As #filesize

    Print #filesize, retStr
    Close #filesize
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

[image]

I couldn't get either of your code samples to run on my machine.